# Markable HTML Table Cell

Tags: qooxdoo, tablecell

i want to achieve a markable HTML Table Cell. For HTML i used the HTML Cellrenderer, which workes well. To get the Cell markable i figured out that i have to set the "-webkit-user-select" form none to text.
For that i wrote my own HTML cellrender. I extended the "qx.ui.table.cellrenderer.Conditional", added the implementation of the HTML Cellrenderer and added this function, which i call in the constructor:

```
_createStyleSheet : function() {
        var colorMgr = qx.theme.manager.Color.getInstance();
        var stylesheet = ".qooxdoo-table-cell {" + qx.bom.element.Style.compile({
            position : "absolute",
            top : "0px",
            overflow : "hidden",
            whiteSpace : "nowrap",
            borderRight : "1px solid " + colorMgr.resolve("table-column-line"),
            padding : "0px 6px",
            cursor : "default",
            textOverflow : "ellipsis",
            userSelect : "text"
        }) + "} " + ".qooxdoo-table-cell-right { text-align:right } " + ".qooxdoo-table-cell-italic { font-style:italic} " + ".qooxdoo-table-cell-bold { font-weight:bold } ";

        if (qx.core.Environment.get("css.boxsizing")) {
            stylesheet += ".qooxdoo-table-cell {" + qx.bom.element.BoxSizing.compile("content-box") + "}";
        }

        qx.ui.table.cellrenderer.Abstract.__clazz.stylesheet = qx.bom.Stylesheet.createElement(stylesheet);
    }
```

Now the cell is markable but the HTML Tabs are not converted.
Also i get the following error: padawan.js:210 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'stylesheet' of undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably didn't copy all the needed code from the constructor of [Abstract Cellrenderer](https://github.com/qooxdoo/qooxdoo/blob/master/framework/source/class/qx/ui/table/cellrenderer/Abstract.js). It would explain why`qx.ui.table.cellrenderer.Abstract.__clazz` is undefined. So you should also add [this part](https://github.com/qooxdoo/qooxdoo/blob/master/framework/source/class/qx/ui/table/cellrenderer/Abstract.js#L37-L49) :

```js
var cr = qx.ui.table.cellrenderer.Abstract;
if (!cr.__clazz)
{
  cr.__clazz = this.self(arguments);
  this._createStyleSheet();

  // add dynamic theme listener
  if (qx.core.Environment.get("qx.dyntheme")) {
    qx.theme.manager.Meta.getInstance().addListener(
      "changeTheme", this._onChangeTheme, this
    );
  }
}
```

and the [_onChangeTheme](https://github.com/qooxdoo/qooxdoo/blob/master/framework/source/class/qx/ui/table/cellrenderer/Abstract.js#L74-L83) method.

Here is a full [playground example](http://demo.qooxdoo.org/devel/playground/#%7B%22code%22%3A%22%252F%252F%2520Create%2520a%2520button%250D%250Avar%2520button1%2520%253D%2520new%2520qx.ui.form.Button(%2522First%2520Button%2522%252C%2520%2522icon%252F22%252Fapps%252Finternet-web-browser.png%2522)%253B%250D%250A%250D%250A%252F%252F%2520Document%2520is%2520the%2520application%2520root%250D%250Avar%2520doc%2520%253D%2520this.getRoot()%253B%250D%250A%250D%250Adoc.add(button1%252C%250D%250A%257B%250D%250A%2520%2520left%2520%253A%2520200%252C%250D%250A%2520%2520top%2520%2520%253A%25200%250D%250A%257D)%253B%250D%250A%250D%250Avar%2520table%2520%253D%2520new%2520qx.ui.table.Table(null)%253B%250D%250A%250D%250Adoc.add(table)%253B%250D%250A%250D%250Abutton1.addListener(%2522execute%2522%252C%2520function(e)%2520%257B%250D%250A%2520%2520table.setFocusedCell()%253B%250D%250A%250D%250A%2520%2520tableModel%2520%253D%2520new%2520qx.ui.table.model.Simple()%253B%250D%250A%2509tableModel.setEditable(false)%253B%250D%250A%2509tableModel.setColumns(%255B%2522test%2522%255D)%253B%250D%250A%2509%250D%250A%2509%2509%2509%250D%250A%2509table.setTableModel(tableModel)%253B%250D%250A%250D%250A%2509table.setColumnWidth(0%252C%2520200)%253B%250D%250A%250D%250A%2509var%2520tableColumnModel%2520%253D%2520table.getTableColumnModel()%253B%250D%250A%250D%250A%2509for%2520(var%2520i%2520%253D%25200%253B%2520i%2520%253C%25201%253B%2520i%252B%252B)%2520%257B%250D%250A%2509%2509%252F%252FtableColumnModel.setDataCellRenderer(i%252C%2520new%2520qx.ui.table.cellrenderer.Html())%253B%250D%250A%2509%2509tableColumnModel.setDataCellRenderer(i%252C%2520new%2520mycellrenderer())%253B%250D%250A%2509%257D%250D%250A%2509%250D%250A%2509tableModel.setData(%255B%255B%2522%253Cb%253Etest%253C%252Fb%253E%2526nbsp%253Btoto%2522%255D%252C%255B%2522%253Ci%253Etest%253C%252Fi%253E%2526%252309%253Bsdf%2522%255D%255D)%253B%250D%250A%250D%250A%257D)%253B%250D%250A%250D%250A%2509%2509%250D%250Aqx.Class.define(%2522mycellrenderer%2522%252C%250D%250A%257B%250D%250A%2520%2520extend%2520%253A%2520qx.ui.table.cellrenderer.Html%252C%250D%250A%250D%250A%250D%250A%2520%2520construct%2520%253A%2520function()%250D%250A%2520%2520%257B%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520this.base(arguments)%253B%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520var%2520cr%2520%253D%2520qx.ui.table.cellrenderer.Abstract%253B%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520if%2520(!cr.__clazz)%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%257B%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520cr.__clazz%2520%253D%2520this.self(arguments)%253B%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520this._createStyleSheet()%253B%250D%250A%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%252F%252F%2520add%2520dynamic%2520theme%2520listener%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520if%2520(qx.core.Environment.get(%2522qx.dyntheme%2522))%2520%257B%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520qx.theme.manager.Meta.getInstance().addListener(%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2522changeTheme%2522%252C%2520this._onChangeTheme%252C%2520this%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520)%253B%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%257D%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%257D%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%250D%250A%2520%2520%257D%252C%250D%250A%2520%2520%250D%250A%2520%2520members%2520%253A%2520%257B%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%252F%252F%2520overridden%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520_onChangeTheme%2520%253A%2520qx.core.Environment.select(%2522qx.dyntheme%2522%252C%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%257B%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2522true%2522%2520%253A%2520function()%2520%257B%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520qx.bom.Stylesheet.removeAllRules(%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520qx.ui.table.cellrenderer.Abstract.__clazz.stylesheet%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520)%253B%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520this._createStyleSheet()%253B%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%257D%252C%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2522false%2522%2520%253A%2520null%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%257D)%252C%250D%250A%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520_createStyleSheet%2520%253A%2520function()%2520%257B%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%252F%252Fthis.base(arguments)%253B%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520console.log(%2522tot2%2522)%253B%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520var%2520colorMgr%2520%253D%2520qx.theme.manager.Color.getInstance()%253B%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520var%2520stylesheet%2520%253D%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2522.qooxdoo-table-cell%2520%257B%2522%2520%252B%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520qx.bom.element.Style.compile(%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%257B%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520position%2520%253A%2520%2522absolute%2522%252C%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520top%253A%2520%25220px%2522%252C%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520overflow%253A%2520%2522hidden%2522%252C%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520whiteSpace%2520%253A%2520%2522nowrap%2522%252C%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520borderRight%2520%253A%2520%25221px%2520solid%2520%2522%2520%252B%2520colorMgr.resolve(%2522table-column-line%2522)%252C%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520padding%2520%253A%2520%25220px%25206px%2522%252C%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520cursor%2520%253A%2520%2522default%2522%252C%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520textOverflow%2520%253A%2520%2522ellipsis%2522%252C%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520userSelect%2520%253A%2520%2522text%2522%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%257D)%2520%252B%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2522%257D%2520%2522%2520%252B%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2522.qooxdoo-table-cell-right%2520%257B%2520text-align%253Aright%2520%257D%2520%2522%2520%252B%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2522.qooxdoo-table-cell-italic%2520%257B%2520font-style%253Aitalic%257D%2520%2522%2520%252B%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2522.qooxdoo-table-cell-bold%2520%257B%2520font-weight%253Abold%2520%257D%2520%2522%253B%250D%250A%2520%2520%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520if%2520(qx.core.Environment.get(%2522css.boxsizing%2522))%2520%257B%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520stylesheet%2520%252B%253D%2520%2522.qooxdoo-table-cell%2520%257B%2522%2520%252B%2520qx.bom.element.BoxSizing.compile(%2522content-box%2522)%2520%252B%2520%2522%257D%2522%253B%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%257D%250D%250A%2520%2520%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520qx.ui.table.cellrenderer.Abstract.__clazz.stylesheet%2520%253D%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520qx.bom.Stylesheet.createElement(stylesheet)%253B%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%257D%250D%250A%2520%2520%257D%250D%250A%257D)%253B%250D%250A%22%2C%20%22mode%22%3A%22ria%22%7D) with an extended HTML CellRenderer.

A better pratice could be to write your own render that implements `ICellRenderer` interface.

Comment: I had to delete the if clause in the Constructor, otherwise it would not override the -webkit-user-select property. Thank you again for your help!